# how can i stop this power shell command for bulk renaming from incrementing so oddly?

Tags: powershell

im trying to bulk rename, but its not working. im using:

```
get-childitem | %{ Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("file s01e{0:D3}.mkv" -f $i++) }
```

but it keep incrementing the numbers every time i run it. the first time it gave me:
file s01e001.mkv,
file s01e002.mkv,
file s01e003.mkv

next time it gave:
file s01e004.mkv,
file s01e005.mkv,
file s01e006.mkv

how do i stop this? i just want it to work how it did the first time.

Comment: Set `$i = 1` before running it

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize $i this way:

```
get-childitem | %{ $i = 1 } { Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ("file s01e{0:D3}.mkv" -f $i++) -whatif }
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was i did not reset $i. oops lol. i just needed to do: $i = 1.